# What's the difference between a React.FunctionComponent and a plain JS function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

These two examples accomplish the same thing. But what are the differences under the hood? I understand functional components vs. React.Component and React.PureComponent, but I haven't been able to find relevant documentation about `React.FunctionComponent`.

**React.FunctionComponent**

```
const MyComponentA: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>I am a React.FunctionComponent</p>
  );
};
```

**Plain JS function component:**

```
const MyComponentB = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>I am a plain JS function component</p>
  );
};
```

Comment: Pretty sure they're exactly the same, but one is TypeScript and the other JavaScript.

Comment: One is TypeScript + JSX, the other is just JSX.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is no difference under the hood. The first one is using TypeScript syntax to indicate the type of `React.FunctionComponent` but they are both plain JS function components.

Comment: there is some minor differences, plain function component could return string, like:
```
const FooString = () => "foo";
```
but you couldn't return string from a FunctionComponent.
```
const BarString: React.FC<{}> = () => "string";
```
hence the return type must be ReactElement|null

Comment: That not true. Under the hood FunctionComponent has at least the `children` property, while in your playin JS function component you would have to define it.

Answer (score 15):

there are some minor differences, plain function component could return string, like:

```
const FooString = () => "foo";
```

but you couldn't return string from a `FunctionComponent`.

```
const BarString: React.FC<{}> = () => "string";
```

hence the return type must be `ReactElement|null`

Comment: I'm new to TS, does anyone know why this is?

Comment: @JoelMellon in the first code example TypeScript will regard the function as just any normal function, and can "see" from it that it returns a `string`, which is all fine. In the section example we tell TS that the fuction is a `React.FC` (which is defined as returning `ReactElement|null`), but because the compiler sees that a string is returned a warning is generated.

Comment: Oh, got it. That makes perfect sense. I didn't really consider that `React.FunctionComponent` is a class and we're effectively type-hinting the function's return value. 10/10 Thanks, friend.

Answer (score 11):

The difference is that `FunctionComponent` comes with one property by default: `children`

```
// Note, no children defined
type Props = {
  name: string
}

const MyComponentA: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  return (
    <p>I am a React.FunctionComponent and my name is {props.name}</p>
    <p>And I have {props.children}</p>
  );
};

const MyComponentB = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <p>I am a plain JS function component</p>
    <p>But my {props.children} are undefined</p>
  );
};
```

For `MyComponentB` the TS compiler would complain that `children` is not defined.

Of course for both components you can just pass children and ignore the TS warning.

Comment: In React in both case props.children works.

Comment: For some reason, I do not get the children's property when using the FunctionComponent, exactly as you do in MyComponentA. I'm using react 18+... Or atleast typescript is showing errors...

Comment: This answer is no longer valid; they removed children from `React.FunctionComponent` because not all components do something with child properties. To make `React.FunctionComponent` accept children nowadays, you need to do: `React.FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<Props>>`.