# Typescript export default: React.FunctionComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How would I go about this in typescript. I know I can do it with giving it a name but thats not what I'm asking. I'm asking how can I still just use default.

```
interface IProps {
  name: string,
  tag: string,
}

export default ({name, tag}: IProps) => {
 ..... my code 
});
```

**Yes I know about this.**

```
const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
...
export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, exactly like you have it, except for the trailing `)` syntax error

```js
import React from "react"

interface IProps {
  name: string,
  tag: string,
}

export default ({name, tag}: IProps): JSX.Element => {
  return <p>hello { name }, some { tag }</p>
} // <- no trailing `)`
```

Or -

```js
import React from "react"

interface IProps {
  name: string,
  tag: string,
}

export default ({name, tag}: IProps): JSX.Element =>
  <p>hello { name }, some { tag }</p>
```

[TypeScript Playground Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOASQAUcwBnOAb1LjkooQSAFxwOMKFQDmAGj5wYKaWIlTKc0gF9ySAB6RYcACZJ6AVwA28ABTdBw2YuVaxrdhwCUYgFIBlAA0AOgBRSyRhajgAXgA+BQAeMFiACyRLSwgeASFGLScOXEZuZ2k4LQSAemTSIA)

That said, a named function is much better, especially for debugging purposes.

Comment: So you wouldn't use React.FunctionComponent instead of JSX.Element ? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @me-me Yep, a functional component is just one that accepts props as an object, and returns JSX compatible content. All you need to do is conform to that expectation.

Comment: @me-me, there's a [subtle difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53935996/633183) using `React.FunctionComponent`. I personally don't see the gain unless you are trying to enforce a very specific constraint.